# Integrating GPS to my application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-location

I am following a [tutorial](http://mobileorchard.com/hello-there-a-corelocation-tutorial/) to integrate GPS to my application. I want to display the `Latitude` and `Longitude` values in the `viewDidLoad` method. According to the tutorial they have displayed it from another method. But i need it to be displayed in `viewDidLoad`. How can i modify the following code to display it in `viewDidLoad` ?

The  `HelloThereController.h` view controller

```
#import "MyCLController.h"

@interface HelloThereViewController : UIViewController <MyCLControllerDelegate> {
    MyCLController *locationController;
}

- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location;
- (void)locationError:(NSError *)error;

@end
```

The  `HelloThereController.m` view controller

```
#import "HelloThereViewController.h"

@implementation HelloThereViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    locationController = [[MyCLController alloc] init];
    locationController.delegate = self;
    [locationController.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    //I need to print the latitude and logitude values here..
}
```

My MyCLController.h class

```
@protocol MyCLControllerDelegate 
@required
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location;
- (void)locationError:(NSError *)error;
@end

@interface MyCLController : NSObject  {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    id delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id  delegate;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;

@end
```

My MyCLController.m class

```
#import "MyCLController.h"

@implementation MyCLController

@synthesize locationManager;
@synthesize delegate;

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self; 
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
         fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    [self.delegate locationUpdate:newLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [self.delegate locationError:error];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self.locationManager release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: You can't rely on the current location being available as soon as the locationManager has been created - `locationManager.location` might be nil. Much better to do this from the location manager's delegate as the tutorial you linked to show.

Comment: Yeah, it gives me 0. But i need to use that data in the viewDidLoad. Is there any workaround for this ? I also tried adding this in viewDidAppear and tried to display it in viewDidLoad, but it gives the same result

Comment: If the phone doesn't know where it is it will take a few seconds for it to determine its location - that's just the way it is.

Comment: Yeah but i can't think about another way to get this done

Answer (score 2):

If this view controller loads as soon as the app loads, you can't.
it takes time for the location manager to get gps updates.

you'll need to display some ui component that lets the user know you're getting the location, such as UIActivityIndicatorView, and setup another method for displaying the coordinates when you get them.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can accelerate the process sacrificing some accuracy setting the desiredAccuracy property. According to the documentation the values are:

```
kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
kCLLocationAccuracyBest
kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
```

Anyway you are interested in the first location, so still according to the documentation:

> When requesting high-accuracy location data, the initial event delivered by the location
>   service may not have the accuracy you requested. **The location service delivers the initial 
>   event as quickly as possible.** It then continues to determine the location with the accuracy 
>   you requested and delivers additional events, as necessary, when that data is available.

You can try starting the location manager in the AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions to have some more time before the view appears. As said by Frederick Cheung, locationManager.location can be nil, so it's better do the operations in the location manager delegate.